# Flask send_file() working with pdf but not with html

Tags: python, flask, azure-blob-storage

I'm having trouble with a flask + azure app. I have some files saved on the storage (pdfs and htmls) and I need to return these files when I invoke the get_file_safe endpoint. This method takes a file_id parameter and accesses the database, goes to blob azure, creates a temporary file and returns that file. When I pass codes that refer to PDF files, it works perfectly and the file is displayed on the screen. When the code matches an HTML file the answer is blank. Does anyone have any idea what it might be? Thank you very much ! (Note: When I used GCP it worked but I had to migrate, so I put here that it is azure).

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request, render_template, session, send_file
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__, ContentSettings

def get_file_safe():
#login and security stuff (...) Logic goes here ->>>

file_id = request.args.get('file_id')
cursor.execute(
    """SELECT link, mimetype from TABLE where id = %s """, (file_id))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
link = rows[0][0]
mimetype = rows[0][1]
filename = link.split("/")[-1]
print("Filename{}".format(filename))
print("Mimetype {}".format(mimetype))

# google cloud version, commented
#client = storage.Client()
#bucket = client.get_bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
#blob = bucket.blob(link)
#with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
#    blob.download_to_filename(temp.name)
#    return send_file(temp.name, attachment_filename=filename)

# azure verson
bucket_name = 'BUCKET-NAME'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=bucket_name, blob=link)
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
    #return send_file(temp.name, attachment_filename=filename, mimetype=mimetype)
    return send_file(temp.name, download_name=filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned only html files not able to read so I tried with html file reading temporary file  display it on the browser

I tried with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:` but getting the black page
And then  I also  tried with  with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:`
And I write data as string able to get the page

**Can you just try  with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:` for html files**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import tempfile
import webbrowser

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("Connection String ")
# Initialise container
blob_container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")
# Get blob
blob_client = blob_container_client.get_blob_client("test.html")

print("downloaded the blob ")
# Download
str=blob_client.download_blob().readall()
print(str)
print(str.decode("utf-8"))
//Getting the Blank Page
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    url = 'file://' + temp.name
    temp.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
    #temp.write(str)
webbrowser.open(url)

//Getting page
html=str.decode("utf-8")
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:
    url = 'file://' + f.name
    f.write(html)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Here is the **OUTPUT** how it looks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfect to me :)!

Comment: Thanks for update , you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Hi @EduardoCarusoBarbosaPacheco ,you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: I did it! Thank you